# Will Laravel 5.2 run on windows 10?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, windows-10, laravel-artisan

I was using Laravel 5.2 on windows 7/Wamp 3.0.6 perfectly fine. My company upgraded to Windows 10 and now localhost:8000 just hangs, and does not load anything. Still using Wamp 3.0.6 on windows 10.

I did a clean install of 5.2 as well as cloning my repo, and they both hang at localhost:8000.

I did a clean install of 5.3 as well as 5.5, and they both seem to work fine. (Does not hang at localhost:8000. It shows the Laravel welcome page)

Has anyone gotten laravel 5.2 to work with windows 10?

Comment: Have you heard about Docker for Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

192..168.0.1 was being blocked at my firewall level, I have to specify host to be 127.0.0.1. Strange

Answer (score 0):

I installed homestead using virtual box on my windows 10. Everything works really neat, plus homestead also has most configurations preset for laravel, as they belong together (as far as I know)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I am running windows 10 via remote desktop, so I tried homestead and it was just too many layers or virtualization and couldn't get the virtualbox to boot.

Answer (score 0):

My setup of Laravel 5.2 is working fine on windows 10. There might be other issues. Please check the laravel error logs, Php error logs and Apache access and error logs to figure-out actual problem.

You can post these error logs here so we can help you out with the issue.